# Putting regex into a variable

Tags: regex, bash, grep

```
REG=/^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(-(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(\.(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*)?(\+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*)?$/g
(echo "1.2.3" | grep -Eq "$REG" ) && echo "matched" || echo "did not match"
```

I get the error:

```
test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 2: `REG=/^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(-(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(\.(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*)?(\+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*)?$/g'
```

Not very much to go on here. Trying to see if `1.2.3` meets the regex expression.

The expression I got from here: https://github.com/mojombo/semver/issues/232

Comment: Walk before you run.  Try an expression with 3-5 characters.  Don't paste in a giant mess, see that it fails, then post it here.  That's off topic.

Comment: `/` delimiters are not supported in bash regex, even `\d` is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes so the shell doesn't barf on special characters.

```
REG='/^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(-(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(\.(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*)?(\+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*)?$/g'
```

Note that this regex will not work with grep. POSIX regex syntax is different and more limited than Perl syntax, which is what you've got.

Comment: Also, the `/ ... /g` is Perl syntax *around* the regex, not part of the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

You ran into two major problems

1. Bash handling special characters, escapes, and anything else it found in your string before storing it. This is solved by single quoting your string to prevent bash expansion/interpretation.
2. The Regex was written in Perl syntax, which grep does not support, it uses POSIX which is slightly different from Perl even though the two are similar. This is solved by removing the surrounding `/` `/g` and replacing all instances of `\d` which is not recognized by POSIX with `[0-9]`.

Result:

```
REG='^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(-(0|[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*)?(\+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*)?$'
```